# Problema para Capturar Error BD Codeigniter

Tags: php, base-de-datos, codeigniter

Quisiera saber porque no arroja el numero de error cuando ingreso un valor equivocado en la Base de Datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la Funcion del Model...

```
<?php

class Pacientes_model extends CI_Model {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

 public function insertar($datos_paciente) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO pacientes (cod_tii_paciente, no_ide_paciente,nom1_paciente, nom2_paciente, ape1_paciente, ape2_paciente, sexo_paciente, cod_est_civil_paciente,fec_nac_paciente, cod_ocup_paciente, dir_paciente, tel_paciente, cel_paciente) "
            . "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    $resultado = $query_result = $this->db->query($sql, $datos_paciente);
    if ($resultado) {
         return $this->db->affected_rows();  
    } else {
        return  $this->db->_error_number(); 
    }
}
}
```

Este es el codigo del controlador

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Pacientes extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Pacientes_model');

}

public function clientes() {
    $this->load->model('pacientes_model');

}

public function guardar() {
    if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) 
    $datos_paciente = ['cod_tii_paciente' => $this->input->post('sel_ti'),
        'no_ide_paciente' => $this->input->post('text_nro_ide'),
        'nom1_paciente' => trim(strtolower($this->input->post('text_nom1'))),
        'nom2_paciente' => trim(strtolower($this->input->post('text_nom2'))),
        'ape1_paciente' => trim(strtolower($this->input->post('text_ape1'))),
        'ape2_paciente' => trim(strtolower($this->input->post('text_ape2'))),
        'sexo_paciente' => $this->input->post('sel_sexo'),
        'cod_est_civil_paciente' => $this->input->post('sel_ec'),
        'fec_nac_paciente' => $this->input->post('text_fec_nac'),
        'cod_ocup_paciente' => $this->input->post('text_cod_ocup'),
        'dir_paciente' => trim(strtolower($this->input->post('text_dir'))),
        'tel_paciente' => trim($this->input->post('text_tel')),
        'cel_paciente' => trim($this->input->post('text_cel'))];

    $message = $this->Pacientes_model->insertar($datos_paciente);

    if ($message) {
        echo $message;
    } else {
        echo $message;
    }
}

}
}
```

Comment: Al momento de lanzar el insert obtienes algun warning o error de php?

Comment: Cuando taro de insertar un texto en un coampo numerico en la tabla no me hace nada, cuando presiono F12 me sale un link de error, y cuando presiono ese linik me guarda puros campos nulos...coloque una imagen

Comment: estas seguro que los datos si llegan al servidor? la petición ajax se puede estar cayendo antes de hacer la inserción. la mejor forma de depurarlo es usando postman.

Comment: - moscoquera eso es lo mas raro que alguna veces si llegan otras veces si llegan...no entiendo donde se pueda estar callendo.

Answer (score 1):

Señores están usando muy malas prácticas de programación, Codeigniter es un framework que tiene muchas ventajas y ofrece un potente mecanismo para gestionar las peticiones de los modelos.
El error que presenta es es 500, es un error por un mal procedimiento en el archivo donde dice que se encontró el error y el servidor simplemente deja de compilar y muestra en error.
Si desea arreglar ese error simplemente debes crear una función en el controlador donde captures los datos y los envíes al modelo, por ejemplo:

```
    public function add() {
        //Te falta agregar codigo de llamada del modelo que usas
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('nombre', 'Nombre', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('campoX', 'campoX', 'required');
        if (!empty($_POST)) {
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
                $values = array('nombre' => $_POST['nombre'],'campoX' => $_POST['campoX']);
                $new = $this->default_model->insert($values);
                redirect('pacientes');
            }
        }
        $data['title_page'] = 'Adicionar Enlace';
        $this->load->view('top', $data);
        $this->load->view('pacientes/add', $data);
        $this->load->view('down', $data);
    }
```

Entonces ese seria el código para el controlador, y el código del modelo es el siguiente:

```
function insertar($datos) {
    return $this->db->insert('nombre_tabla', $datos);
}
```

Si no comprende bien puede contactarme para darle mejor explicación.